# redirect in React - Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I watched certain tutorial to understand how to do routing but they all were theoretical or I wasn't able to understand their implementation.

Can someone help me by guiding me to route/re-direct this one component as an example so that I can setup routes for other components as well.

I am using express.js for the server side and react for client side

In my react, I sent a request using axious to my server like this (this happens in stateful signup container)

```
 axios.post('/user', {
        emailAddress: this.state.emailAddress,
            password: this.state.password
        })
      .then((response) => {
                if (!response.data.error) {
                    console.log('successful signup')
                } else {
                    console.log('username already taken')
                }
            })
        .catch(error => {
                console.log('signup error: ')
                console.log(error)
            })
```

In my server route, I take this data, store in my mongoose and then want to redirect to my login page (or any page). My server route looks like this

```
router.post("/", function(req, res) {
  console.log("user login post request");
  console.log(req.body.emailAddress)
  User.findOne({username: req.body.emailAddress}, function(err, user){
      if (err) {
        console.log('post error: ', err)

        }
      else if (user) {
        console.log("already exsist")
        res.json({
            error: 'user exsist'
        })
      }
      else {
        console.log("here new user")
        User.register(new User({username: req.body.emailAddress }), req.body.password, function(error, user){
          if (error) {
            console.log("error -> Post request from user");
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            req.logIn(user, function (err) {
             if (err) {
               return next(err);
                   }
              return res.json(user) // send whatever you want or redirect
             });

          }
        })
      }
  })
})
```

In ejs, we used to do res.render but then that is EJS and I doesn't work on react so can someone help me/guide in setting up routes so that if user is successfully registered then we can redirect him to login component.

The least I have already done is npm install react-router-dom --save

Comment: There's a change in thinking that needs to happen here. When you 'redirect' in React, you're not serving a new page. You're simply changing which components render based on the url. What needs to happen here is you need to wait for the response from the server, and do your redirect in React.

Comment: Since you are new to react, you need to go through some stuff. The links which I have shared will help. I have also created a login and signup page, and redirected the user accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Based upon the message you are getting from the server, you can set a state, and can redirect accordingly.

You can include this code in the react component which you are rendering:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

//Initializing the state:
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        fireRedirect: false
    };
}

//Setting state as message received from server:
if (!response.data.error) {
    console.log('successful signup');
    this.setState({
        fireRedirect: true
    });
}

//Include this code snippet inside render block
{this.state.fireRedirect && <Redirect to='/dashboard' push={true} />}
```

For detailed info refer here: [Link](https://github.com/nyctophiliacme/Chat-App/blob/master/client/src/Signup.js)

```
//For handling of routes you can include similar code in index.js / App.js
<Route exact path="/dashboard" 
       render={() => <Dashboard/>} />
```

Detailed info: [Link](https://github.com/nyctophiliacme/Chat-App/blob/master/client/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you, this is a great neat solution. It took a while to find this among all express solutions on the web.

Answer (score 2):

Import `BrowserRouter` in your index.js

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Wrap your App component to `BrowserRouter`

```
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Set up routes in your App.js

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
// import your components...

<Switch>
        // Example routes...
        <Route exact path='/' component={yourMainComponent} />
        <Route exact path='/login' component={yourLoginComponent} />
        ...
</Switch>
```

In your axios function you can redirect

```
axios.post('/user', {
    emailAddress: this.state.emailAddress,
        password: this.state.password
    })
  .then((response) => {
            if (!response.data.error) {
                console.log('successful signup')
            } else {
                console.log('username already taken')
            }

            // Redirect
            this.props.history.replace('/path-to-redirect');
        })
    .catch(error => {
            console.log('signup error: ')
            console.log(error)
        })
```

Other approach would be to use the `Redirect` component from `react-router-dom`.